# Can't call some Swift functions from Objective-c (others work)

Tags: objective-c, swift

I've defined two different functions in Swift, just to test out how to call from Objective-C ... one of them works, and one doesn't!

I've defined them here:

```
public extension UIViewController {
    func testAddingOperationTo(array: inout  [Operation]) -> Operation {
        let completionBlock = BlockOperation (block: {
            print("completionOperation")
        })

        return completionBlock;
    }

    func testSomethingWith (count: Int){
        print("testing something \(count)")
    }
}
```

In Objective-C, I've imported the correct header file, and I can call the 2nd method just fine:

```
[self testSomethingWithCount:0];
```

But the first one doesn't work ... it doesn't show up in Xcode auto-complete, and even if I manually type it, it gives build errors. I want to call it like this:

```
NSOperation *completionOperation = [self testAddingOperationToArray: operationsList];
```

What is wrong here? Have I defined the function incorrectly, or is there some obscure rule about Swift that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put `@objc` in front of the method declaration to tell the Swift compiler that you specifically want to use a method from Objective-C. Among other effects, this makes the compiler issue an error if the method is not callable from Objective-C for some reason:

```
@objc func testAddingOperationTo(array:  [Operation]) -> Operation {
// Method cannot be marked @objc because the type of the parameter cannot be represented in Objective-C
```

It would be nice if the compiler told you **which** parameter's type is not represented, but as of Xcode 9 beta 2, it doesn't.

Anyway, the problem in this case is that Swift `inout` parameters cannot be represented in Objective-C. If you don't need the parameter to be `inout`, just take out that keyword and the method will be bridged to Objective-C.

If you need to pass in an array that the function can modify, one way is to add another version that takes an `NSMutableArray`. The second version is bridged to Objective-C:

```
func testAddingOperation(to array: inout [Operation]) {
    let completionBlock = BlockOperation (block: {
        print("completionOperation")
    })
    array.append(completionBlock)
}

@objc func testAddingOperation(toOperations mutableArray: NSMutableArray) {
    var array = mutableArray.map({ $0 as! Operation })
    testAddingOperation(to: &array)
    mutableArray.replaceObjects(in: NSRange(location: 0, length: mutableArray.count), withObjectsFrom: array)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Importing the header works **most of the time**. However, there are some exceptions.

The exception is that the type that is used is a **bridged type** (for example, `NSString` and `String`). Your `inout` has to be rewritten to `UnsafeMutablePointer` as Objective C doesn't recognise `inout`. So you have to either use the Objective C type or write a function for both types.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean ... how would I use an Objective-C type in Swift? How would I rewrite the method with UnsafeMutablePointer and still be able to add operations to the array passed in?

Comment: Swift `Array` is bridged to/from `NSArray`. The problem is the use of `inout`, not the use of `Array`.